# Is asp.net MVC2 included in .net 4.0 framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0

I've installed .net 4 in the server.
Now I don't know if I must install the MVC 2 for VS2008 or what because I got this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, 
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. 
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

VS 2010 comes with MVC 2, but it's not a part of the .NET Framework proper.  This means that if you go download the .NET Framework 4 redistributable, it will not include the MVC 2 runtime.

But since MVC is bin-deployable, this is fine.  Your application - when deployed to a .NET 3.5 SP1 or .NET 4 server - will just copy System.Web.Mvc.dll to its /bin folder, and everything will run as expected.  MVC runs just fine in Medium Trust.

To do a **server wide install** you need to download `AspNetMVC2_VS2008.exe` from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C9BA1FE1-3BA8-439A-9E21-DEF90A8615A9&displaylang=en), rename the `.exe` to `.zip` and inside the `mvcruntime` sub-folder you'll find the `AspNetMVC2.msi` file.

Then you have to run:

```
msiexec /i AspNetMVC2.msi /l*v .\mvc.log MVC_SERVER_INSTALL="YES"
```

Comment: @Levi: Thanks. Copy local and works. Haacked and team must be preparing the final release for .net 4

Comment: @Eduardo - There are no plans to roll the MVC framework into the .NET framework.  This could change, obviously, but it's overwhelmingly likely that all future releases will continue to be out-of-band.

Comment: I mean a .net 4 compiled setup of MVC 2 ready to go to the shared assemblies folder.

Comment: MVC 2 is compiled against .NET 3.5 SP1, not .NET 4.  (So MVC 2 will work on .NET 4, it just can't take advantage of .NET 4-specific functionality.)  The first release of MVC that will be compiled against .NET 4 is MVC 3.

Answer (score 6):

by default the System.Web.Mvc.dll is not included when you compile an MVC 2 project;
you have to change the setting "Copy Local" to True on the Reference properties to get the file in your /bin

Comment: Thanks!  This worked great for me.  I didn't need to copy the file locally on my machine, but I did need to when running on the server.  Can you explain why this is necessary?