# How to install ASP.net MVC 2 on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, installation, windows-server-2008

Currently I'm in the process of deploying my ASP.net MVC 2 project on a Windows Server 2008 R2 web server. This web server already has the .net 4 Framework installed, but doesn't have any MVC dll's in the GAC.

So deployment on IIS succeeds, but when I start up the web application in the browser, it results in this message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Of course I can Google myself too and it mainly suggests:

- Copying the MVC dll's (System.Web.Mvc.dll, .Routing.dll, etc) to the output directory;
- Downloading an RTM version of ASP.net MVC 2 on top of .net 3.5 Framework.

Neither of them I'd like to do. I just want to install ASP.net MVC 2 to the GAC of my web server. So my question is:

- Which installation does actually contain ASP.net MVC 2 for installation on top of .net 4?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>If you already have .NET 4.0 installed on the server and your application is targeting .NET 4.0 you don't need to install anything. ASP.NET MVC 2 is included in .NET 4.0. Just make sure that your web application is targeting .NET 4.0 and using the assemblies already present in the GAC. If you are targeting .NET 3.5 (CLR 2.0 application pool) you will need to install the ASP.NET MVC 2.0 by [downloading it from MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C9BA1FE1-3BA8-439A-9E21-DEF90A8615A9&displaylang=en).</strike>

---

UPDATE:

ASP.NET MVC 2 is included in the VS2010 install and not part of .NET 4.0. So you need to [download and install it from MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C9BA1FE1-3BA8-439A-9E21-DEF90A8615A9&displaylang=en).

Comment: I checked, the web application is running on .net 4. Unfortunately no record of System.Web.Mvc.dll in the GAC. So I guess it's not installed decently?

Comment: @Monty, I was wrong, ASP.NET MVC 2 is not part of .NET 4.0. It is installed with VS2010. So you might need installing the package which is compatible with both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0

Comment: thanks for clarification. Kind of weird, because its using the framework 'own' namespaces like System.Web ... apparently that doesn't mean it's linked to the actual .net 4 framework. Also found this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633504/is-asp-net-mvc2-included-in-net-4-0-framework.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) to setup MVC 2 on your server. It's included in Windows 2008 R2 and available as a free download.
With WPI it's a matter of selecting the desired technologies and clicking Ok to install.