# Where can i download asp.net mvc 2 (two)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, iis-7.5

My system administrator and i would like to run asp.net mvc2 and asp.net mvc3 side-by-side. When prompted, my sys admin upgraded IIS7.5 to asp.net mvc3, but that seems to have removed asp.net mvc2.

We've been googling for a little while now, and we can't find a download link for asp.net mvc2. It's all version 3.

Do you guys know where we could find an mvc2 download? My sys admin has also tried the Web Platform Installer, but he says that it's broken and won't run.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you put the mvc dll in the bin directory of your projects? That way you don't need to install anything on the server.

Comment: that is also true. But we intend to be running multiple (hundreds) of sites on this server. Rather than have a copy of the dll in every site's bin, we'd rather save the space and install it server-wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [download it from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en).

Comment: thank you for the link. We do have 4.0 installed but for some reason mvc doesn't seem to be present after we updated to mvc3.

Comment: @quakkels, my mistake, ASP.NET MVC 2 is not included in .NET 4.0. It is included in VS 2010. You need to download and install it. Here's an answer you might find useful for doing a server install: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633504/is-asp-net-mvc2-included-in-net-4-0-framework/2633577#2633577

Answer (score 1):

try [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en)