# ASP .NET Web Forms: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net, .net

I moved my existing ASP .NET web sites and web applications to a new server, and I'm getting the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I located this assembly on my computer, and copied it to the BIN folder of my web site. It gives a new error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

Does this mean ASP .NET is not properly installed on the server machine? How do I go about fixing this? I also noticed that the assembly is present on my computer somewhere in the `Program Files (x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET` folder. However, the `Program Files (x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET` folder does not exist on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: I installed both ASP .NET Web Pages and ASP.NET MVC 4 on the server. This installed the missing assemblies and created the folders that were missing.

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions speak for  themselves: Your project has referenced version 2.0.0.0 of this assembly and you have copied version 1.0.0.0

Find the correct version and you'll be OK

Comment: Actually, I did copy the 2.0.0.0 version, which is why I'm surprised too. I think this may have something to do with the fact that the Program Files (x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET folder is missing from the server.

Comment: I think that folder is created by visual studio, so it's absent on the server. Can you check if you copied the correct assembly? And if so, use `Process Monitor` to find where ASP.NET is looking for it?

Comment: Will try Process Monitor, thank you. As for the folder, I can see it's present on my original server, but not on the new server. Visual Studio is not installed on any of the servers so it can't be a VS folder.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708046/how-do-i-deploy-an-asp-net-mvc3-application

Comment: And I think this is what you should install: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15979&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True

Comment: Thank you for your help - There was some helpful information there. I will try installing that and get back to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57831/discussion-between-mehdi-maujood-and-alireza).

Comment: The solution: Installed both ASP.NET Web Pages and ASP.NET MVC 4 on the server. This installed the missing assemblies and created the folders I mentioned.